# DATEPART missing months

Tags: sql-server

Good evening help me with this query (sqlserver):

```
SELECT
DATEPART (YEAR, spese_generali.data) as 'YEAR',
DATEPART (MONTH, spese_generali.data) as 'MONTH',
SUM (spese_generali.importo) as amount
FROM spese_generali 
group by DATEPART (MONTH, spese_generali.data), 
         DATEPART (YEAR,spese_generali.data) 
order by 'YEAR'
```

The result is this:

```
YEAR   MONTH  amount
2017   6      296.00
2018   1      131.00
2018   2      154.00
2018   3      441.00
etc.
```

I would like the result to be this:

```
YEAR   MONTH  amount
2017   6      296.00
2017   7      0
2017   8      0
2017   9      0
2017   10     0
2017   11     0
2017   12     0
2018   1      131.00
2018   2      154.00
2018   3      441.00
etc.
```

that is, for the missing months, you must enter 0 at the collection amount

Comment: SQL Server can't return those if they don't exist in your spese_generali table. Need a calendar table or a similar solution. Google SQL Gaps and Islands.

Comment: [The Calendar Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a calendar table, you can make one on the fly fairly easily. Something like the following:

```
DECLARE 
    @beg_date DATE = '2017-06-01',
    @end_date DATE = '2018-11-01';

WITH 
    cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)), 
    cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),
    cte_Calendar (d) AS (
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @beg_date, @end_date) + 1)
            DATEADD(MONTH, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.n) -1, @beg_date)
        FROM
            cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b
        )

SELECT
    YEAR = DATEPART(YEAR, c.d),
    MONTH = DATEPART(MONTH, c.d),
    amount = SUM(sg.importo)
FROM
    cte_Calendar c
    LEFT JOIN dbo.spese_generali sg
        ON sg.date >= c.d
        AND sg.date < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, c.d)
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(MONTH, c.d),
    DATEPART(YEAR, c.d)
ORDER BY
    'YEAR';
```